# My primeng schedule appears but not events

Tags: angular, calendar, primeng, schedule

I am using primeng schedule, the calendar appears fine but the events are not displaying as shown in the image below.
the project is rather simple.  just use primeng with schedule.  nothing complicated.  I have attached my code.  if any has come across this problem before and has a solution for it.  Your help will be very much appreciated.  Thank you so much

[image]

angular.json

```
"styles": [
    "src/styles.css"
],
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
    "node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js",
    "node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.js"
],
```

style.css

```
@import "~primeicons/primeicons.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css";
@import "~primeng/resources/primeng.min.css";
@import "~fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css";
@import "~fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.css";
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/common": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/compiler": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/core": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/forms": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/http": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/router": "^6.1.0",
"core-js": "^2.5.4",
"fullcalendar": "^4.0.0-alpha",
"fullcalendar-scheduler": "^1.9.4",
"moment": "^2.22.2",
"primeicons": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
"primeng": "^6.1.2",
"rxjs": "^6.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.7.0",
"@angular/cli": "~6.1.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.1.0",
"@angular/language-service": "^6.1.0",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/node": "~8.9.4",
"codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
"jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
"karma": "~1.7.1",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.0",
"karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
"protractor": "~5.4.0",
"ts-node": "~5.0.1",
"tslint": "~5.9.1",
"typescript": "~2.7.2"
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import {ButtonModule} from 'primeng/button';
import {ScheduleModule} from 'primeng/schedule';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

// import 'fullcalendar';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent
    ],
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ButtonModule,
    ScheduleModule
],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<p-schedule [events]="events" [header]="headerConfig" ></p-schedule>`,
    styles: ['']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    headerConfig: any;
    title = 'primecalendar';
    events: any[];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.headerConfig = {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    };

    this.events = [
        {
            "title": "All Day Event",
            "start": '2018-08-01'
        },
        {
             "title": "Long Event",
             "start": "2018-08-07",
             "end": "2018-08-10"
        },
        {
             "title": "Repeating Event",
             "start": "2018-08-09T16:00:00"
        },
        {
             "title": "Repeating Event",
             "start": "2018-08-16T16:00:00"
        },
        {
             "title": "Conference",
             "start": "2018-08-11",
              "end": "2018-08-13"
        }
];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the jquery module which might be the root cause of the issue.

Also no need to include the full calendar scheduler location

[image]

As you can see from the above picture. Fullcalendar scheduler is not required.  so you can remove the entry

```
"node_modules/fullcalendar-scheduler/dist/scheduler.min.js"
```

In your command prompt :

```
npm install jquery --save
```

**Package.json** should include: jquery

```
  " jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.10",
    "minimist": "^1.2.0",
```

Also I have noticed you are not serving the node modules from root folder. Again it depends where you setup. So the updated angular.json file should include juery, moment and full calendear.js. Styling of full calendar.css is optional.

**angular.json file**

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.js",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
        "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js"
      ],

 "styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
        "../node_modules/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css",
        "styles.scss"
      ],
```

**My working example:**

[image]

Hope the above will definitely work.